# partition $1,2,...,12$ into $6$ pair of relatively prime numbers

Tags: combinatorics

find all solution to partitioning $1,2,...,12$ into $6$ pair of relatively prime numbers

Obviously brute forcing this would work, but I was wondering if there was any 'cleaner' solutions?

Comment: First, you can only pair odd numbers with even numbers. Write all evens in one column, and all odds in another column. For each pair of odd and even that both are divisible by 3, draw s line between them. So the same for divisible by 5. Now to get the answer fine odd-even pairs with no lines between them.

Comment: Frame this as follows : consider the graph on $\{1,2,...,12\}$ with $a \sim b$ if and only if $\gcd(a,b) = 1$. Then, what you are asking for is a *perfect matching* of this graph. This graph is a very haywire graph, since for example it contains a lot of cliques (complete subgraphs), and these alone will have plenty of permutations among themselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each even number must be paired with an odd number; since there are $6$ even numbers and $6$ odd numbers, each odd number must be paired with an even number.

The odd numbers $3$ and $9$ must be paired with even numbers not divisible by $3$, that is, with $2$, $4$, $8$, or $10$. There are $4\cdot3=12$ ways to do this; $3\cdot2=6$ ways in which $10$ is not used, and $6$ ways in which $10$ is used.

The number $5$ may be paired with any unused even number except $10$, so the total number of ways to pair $3$, $9$, and $5$ with even numbers is $6\cdot3+6\cdot4=42$.

Finally, the remaining odd numbers $1$, $7$, and $11$ can be paired with any unused even numbers, so the total number of solutions is $42\cdot3!=252$.